# how to run storybook v7 within nextjs 13 (not on separate port)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, storybook

TLDR: Is it possible to run storybook as part of my nextjs app (not in a separate port). Right now I need to run my nextjs project on port 3000 and storybook on port 6006. I would like to be able to view the storybook UI as a nextJS page/route.

Details:

I am building a nextjs project that uses storybook to showcase some components.

These are the specific versions these packages:

```
{
  "name": "nextjs-storybook-temp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "URL=http://localhost:3000 && (open $URL || cmd.exe /c start $URL) && next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@dnd-kit/sortable": "^8.0.0",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "chonky": "^2.3.2",
    "chonky-icon-fontawesome": "^2.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-imask": "^7.1.3",
    "react-js-cron": "^5.0.1",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.3.4",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3",
    "react-use": "^17.4.2",
    "react18-json-view": "^0.2.6",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.31",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-styling-webpack": "^0.0.5",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/manager-api": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "@storybook/theming": "^7.4.6",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.4",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "storybook": "^7.4.6",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Right now, I need to run
`npm run storybook`

and import the standalone storybook app within an iframe in a nextjs page like so:

```
export default function Components() {
  return (
    <iframe
      className="vh-100 position-relative z-1"
      src="http://localhost:6006/"
      style={{
        // position: "relative",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        border: "none",
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        overflow: "hidden",
        zIndex: 999999,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Here's my storybook main.js

```
const config = {
  stories: [
    "../components/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-styling-webpack",
    ({
        name: "@storybook/addon-styling-webpack",

        options: {
          rules: [{
        test: /\.css$/,
        sideEffects: true,
        use: [
            require.resolve("style-loader"),
            {
                loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
                options: {
                    
                    
                },
            },
        ],
      },{
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        sideEffects: true,
        use: [
            require.resolve("style-loader"),
            {
                loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
                options: {
                    
                    importLoaders: 2,
                },
            },
            require.resolve("resolve-url-loader"),
            {
                loader: require.resolve("sass-loader"),
                options: {
                    implementation: require.resolve("sass"),
                    sourceMap: true,
                    sassOptions: {},
                },
            },
        ],
      },],
        }
    })
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  // staticDirs: ['../public'],
};
export default config;
```

Comment: As far as i know, it is not possible to run Storybook as part of a Next.js app on the same port. Storybook is typically designed to run as a separate development environment for showcasing components and UI elements. It's commonly run on a different port to keep it isolated from the main application.